# GOOGLE Forms and Mapping Location

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Can you use Google Form to collect information about the activities of users and drawing a map showing a radius where these activities occurred? Like show me a map that shows all the stores under 23456 Zip Code?

So we will have the store street and zip codes entered by the user to Google Form but we will need to draw a map showing the locations?

What we are trying to find out is the mapping options of Google Forms or how the information inputted or imported to Google Form can be used for drawing maps or even drawing a radius of where the most Giant Foods are located in a community?

Please help if you could explain. 
Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Forms doesn't include any mapping options.

You could use it to collect the data, then you should use something else to display the collected data as you describe.

i.e. You could use Google Apps Script to get the data collected by a Google Form to create a kml file then import that file into Google Maps.

Reference

- [Google Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/9055404?hl=en&ref_topic=1382883)

Comment: Thank you Ruben. Do you think security wise the Google Forms can be used for personal information such as PII information that may include Name, Address? etc? Thanks a lot

Comment: @aminihockey Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/someone-answers)

Comment: Regarding the question in the comment, it depends on how you set your form settings. For further details please post a new question.